# Is UNUserNotification have option to show notification only on apple watch?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch

I am developing apple watch app which have the functionality to show a notification to User after **every 2 or 3 or 5 min.**

I have achieved this functionality through iOS `UNUserNotification` and its works perfectly.

But what I want here is User can see all notifications only on Apple watch not on iPhone.

Right now it's showing on both iPhone & Apple watch.

Is it possible to show notifications only on the Apple watch?

I have implemented the below code for `UserNotification`.

```
func scheduleNotification(at date: Date) {

        
        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: (1*60), repeats: true)
        
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "Test Reminder"
        content.body = "Show More detail in Body!"
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
        content.categoryIdentifier = "myCategory"
        
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "logo", ofType: "png") {
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
            
            do {
                let attachment = try UNNotificationAttachment(identifier: "logo", url: url, options: nil)
                content.attachments = [attachment]
            } catch {
                print("The attachment was not loaded.")
            }
        }
        
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "textNotification", content: content, trigger: trigger)
        
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) {(error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Uh oh! We had an error: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible.
The system decides automatically where to show the notifications, developers have no control over this.
The notification will be displayed on the Apple Watch if the paired iPhone is locked and the Watch is worn by the user. In any other case, the notification will be displayed on the iPhone.

See [Notifications on your Apple Watch](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204791)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make the notification appear only on watch if you will trigger the **Local** notification from **WatchKit Extension**.
Please see the corresponding documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/notifications/taking_advantage_of_notification_forwarding?changes=__5